# Why is boost::auto_cpu_timer showing > 100% utilization?

Tags: c++, boost

To do timing comparisons I wanted to use boost::timer. Here is a simple test case that performs some vector operations:

```
std::vector<float> hv( 1000*1000 );
std::generate(hv.begin(), hv.end(), rand);
{
    boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer t;
    std::transform(hv.begin(), hv.end(), hv.begin(), sqrtf);
}
```

The confusing part is that boost::timer reports this:

> 0.011577s wall, 0.020000s user + 0.000000s system = 0.020000s CPU (172.8%)

How can my userspace time exceed wall time?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely if you use threads, it will display the CPU time spent on all threads in the process

Comment: This is pretty much the entirety of main(). No additional threads are spawned by me.

Answer (score 0):

By adding more test code the userspace time will jump to 0.03s and then to 0.04s

So it looks like the userspace duration is only accurate to within 10 ms causing the CPU utilization calculation to be wrong.

Comment: This is indeed a known fact when using the old boost timer implementations on some platforms. _"Although nanosecond_type is capable of representing one  nanosecond, the actual resolution of common operating system timers may be much lower. For wall clock time on desktop systems circa 2010, resolution is often no better than than one microsecond. For user and system time, typical resolution is 15 milliseconds on Windows and 10 milliseconds on POSIX."_ http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/timer/doc/cpu_timers.html